# Which xinput setting will reverse the direction of my mouse's scroll wheel?

Tags: ubuntu, scroll, vertical-scrolling, xinput, scrollwheel

I am attempting to follow the advice of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604002/mouse-wheel-scrolls-in-reversed-direction) question, using the [xinput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xinput) tool to enable natural scrolling for my mouse's scroll wheel.

I list my input devices via `$ xinput list` and get the following:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell USB Optical Mouse               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The relevant device is the `Dell Dell USB Optical Mouse id=14`. I list the properties of that device via `$ xinput list-props 14`, and get

```
$ xinput list-props 14
Device 'Dell Dell USB Optical Mouse':
        Device Enabled (140):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (266):     0
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):       1.000000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (268):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (269):    10.000000
        Device Product ID (260):        16700, 12306
        Device Node (261):      "/dev/input/event12"
        Evdev Axis Inversion (306):     0, 0
        Evdev Axes Swap (308):  0
        Axis Labels (309):      "Rel X" (150), "Rel Y" (151), "Rel Vert Wheel" (775)
        Button Labels (310):    "Button Left" (143), "Button Middle" (144), "Button Right" (145), "Button Wheel Up" (146), "Button Wheel Down" (147), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (148), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (149)
        Evdev Scrolling Distance (311): 1, 1, 1
        Evdev Middle Button Emulation (312):    0
        Evdev Middle Button Timeout (313):      50
        Evdev Third Button Emulation (314):     0
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (315):     1000
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (316):      3
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (317):   20
        Evdev Wheel Emulation (318):    0
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (319):       0, 0, 4, 5
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (320):    10
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (321):    200
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (322):     4
        Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (323):  0
```

**Which (if any) of these can I change to reverse the scroll wheel direction?**

I tried adjusting the `Evdev Axis Inversion (306)` property via command `$ xinput set-prop 14 306 1, 1`, but that is apparently for mouse movement direction, not scroll wheel direction -- I had to change that back.

Do any of these `xinput` settings reverse the scroll wheel direction? If not then perhaps I will need to try another method. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Try to Run

```
$ xinput set-prop 14 311 -1 1 1
```

to set "*Evdev Scrolling Distance*" to negative values for vertical moves.